# Batch enabling MapTips

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

In the layer properties of each layer there is an option "Show MapTips using the display expression" that is by default disabled and I would like to find out if there is a way to enable this option by default for all layers or by using arcpy.

I have tried to run arcpy.UpdateLayer but that would update either only the symbology properties or every layer property.

[image: Layer Properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have seen this option grayed out it is because the shapefile (or feature class) does not have a spatial index.

To address this from a script I would use the [Add Spatial Index (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000060000000) tool.

To do it on every shapefile (feature class) I would use arcpy.da.Walk to visit every workspace and run the tool on any shapefiles (feature classes) found.

If your question is about checking/unchecking the option then this [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/90805) suggests that the only way to do that is via ArcObjects.